# How to create a page with 4 buttons that play audio from gdrive?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a simple html page with 4 button that plays audio from my gdrive.
How can I add three additional audios each to a different button and allowing only one to be played at a time while pausing the others?
This is the code with the first working button. Thank you in advance for your help.

```html
<div class="test">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <p>Click here</p>
      <img src="media/play.png" id="icon"></li>
    <li>
      <p>Click here</p>
      <img src="media/play.png" id="icon2"></li>
    <li>
      <p>Click here</p>
      <img src="media/play.png" id="icon3"></li>
    <li>
      <p>Click here</p>
      <img src="media/play.png" id="icon4"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<audio id="mySong">
    <source src="https://drive.google.com/u/0/uc?id=1HqQ6zRurKoFRHBak1gmwsPG9Z6P8qF2G&export=download" type="audio/mp3"> </audio>

<script>
  var mySong = document.getElementById("mySong");
  var icon = document.getElementById("icon");

  icon.onclick = function() {
    if (mySong.paused) {
      mySong.play();
      icon.src = "media/pause.png";
    } else {
      mySong.pause();
      icon.src = "media/play.png";
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a list of all the icons and songs.
When you play one song, all of the others get paused.

In this example, all the tunes are the same.
Change the audio links if you want them to be different.

```html
<ul>
  <li><p>Click here</p><img src = media/play.png id = icon1></li>
  <li><p>Click here</p><img src = media/play.png id = icon2></li>
  <li><p>Click here</p><img src = media/play.png id = icon3></li>
  <li><p>Click here</p><img src = media/play.png id = icon4></li>
</ul>

<audio id = song1>
  <source src = "https://drive.google.com/u/0/uc?id=1HqQ6zRurKoFRHBak1gmwsPG9Z6P8qF2G&export=download" type = audio/mp3>
</audio>

<audio id = song2>
  <source src = "https://drive.google.com/u/0/uc?id=1HqQ6zRurKoFRHBak1gmwsPG9Z6P8qF2G&export=download" type = audio/mp3>
</audio>

<audio id = song3>
  <source src = "https://drive.google.com/u/0/uc?id=1HqQ6zRurKoFRHBak1gmwsPG9Z6P8qF2G&export=download" type = audio/mp3>
</audio>

<audio id = song4>
  <source src = "https://drive.google.com/u/0/uc?id=1HqQ6zRurKoFRHBak1gmwsPG9Z6P8qF2G&export=download" type = audio/mp3>
</audio>
    
<script>
    let songs = [song1, song2, song3, song4]
    let icons = [icon1, icon2, icon3, icon4]

    icons.forEach((icon, index) => {
      icon.onclick = function() {
        if (songs[index].paused) {
          songs.forEach(song => song.pause())
          icons.forEach(icon => icon.src = "media/play.png")
          songs[index].play()

          icon.src = "media/pause.png"
        }

        else {
          songs[index].pause()
          icon.src = "media/play.png"
        }
      }
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, the pause and play images didn't work properly. Just fixed it.